# Origins of this interesting optical phenomenon?

Tags: optics, visible-light, dispersion

[image]

Sunlight reflecting off my glasses seem to disperse into these distinct red and blue bands. The glasses are acting as some sort of a prism to split the light. The glasses do have some reflective coating (if that helps).

Any thoughts on what might be causing these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anti-reflective coating would explain it. The coating is a thin film interference filter that is designed to reduce reflections and its performance changes with wavelength and angle of incident of the light. So instead of the glasses strongly reflecting white light, the reflection is reduced. But it is not evenly reduced over the whole visible spectrum, resulting in some colors.